# Является ли верной структура приложения

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, типы

Является ли верным написание backend на js, а frontend на ts? Использую postgresql express node angular 4. В качестве orm использую sequuelize. Так вот, sequelize (как для новичка) сложновато перевести на ts и по-этому хоче перевести бек на js, а фронт оставить на ts.

Comment: есть более тайпскриптовые orm, например, https://typeorm.io/ и https://mikro-orm.io/

Comment: Верным является любое обращение с TS, даже его полное игнорирование с использованием только JS. Это определяется индивидуальными взглядами на целесообразность, а общего правила "для всех и на все возможные случаи" не существует. Тут можно разве что посоветовать вводить типизацию постепенно, не создавая себе сразу дополнительных сложных задач... т.е. не давать инструментам мешать непосредственно работе, результативности. _//Ну, и частный вредный совет от противника вредных инструментов (который можно смело игнорировать): фтопку TS, ибо тесты были и будут намного надежнее._

Answer (score 0):

На sequelize есть `definetlyTyped`. Смотри [здесь](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/sequelize).

Его надо просто подгрузить к проекту и все будет хорошо. То есть вы можете писать бэкенд на ts. Не нужно делать лишние движения в сторону js, так как ts в общем то понимает js, но js не является ts.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я сейчас посматриваю в сторону sequelize-typescript

Comment: @Vlad Если помогло, то надо ставить галочку и поднимать.